# Python - SQLite3 - Update not working via input

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to Update my DB via Input.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('datenbank.db')
print ("Opened database successfully")

kunde1 = input("Der Kundename: ")
anzahl1 = input("Anzahl Bewertung: ")


conn.execute('''UPDATE kundenname SET anzahl = ? WHERE kundename = ?''',    
(anzahl1, kunde1))
conn.commit
```

it dosent Show any Errors.. but it get not updated in DB?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: `conn.commit` does not call the function,you need `conn.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

`conn.commit` does not call `commit`, rather, it is merely accessing its instance. Therefore, a simple `commit` call and a file close should fix the problem:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('datenbank.db')
print ("Opened database successfully")
kunde1 = input("Der Kundename: ")
anzahl1 = input("Anzahl Bewertung: ")
conn.execute('''UPDATE kundenname SET anzahl = ? WHERE kundename = ?''', (anzahl1, kunde1))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

since you are inputting data in the middle of the execution sequence, it may be better to use a `contextmanager`:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def update_database(kunde1, anzahl1):
   conn = sqlite3.connect('datenbank.db')
   print ("Opened database successfully")
   yield conn #can be used later to update database in or outside the scope of "with"
   conn.execute('''UPDATE kundenname SET anzahl = ? WHERE kundename = ?''', (anzahl1, kunde1))
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()

with update_database(input("Der Kundename: "), input("Anzahl Bewertung: ")) as b:
   pass #do something after
```